# How should I wait for props to be ready in React?

Tags: mongodb, reactjs

Using Meteor/React/Mongo. With a Wrapper Parent component that fetches data from mongo and passes it down as props - I often have the issue that props are not yet ready when the constructor is called. I can see a couple different ways of working around this (e.g. making use of ComponentWillReceiveProps) but I would rather follow best practice. Is there a better way to determine that all the props are present - within the context of React Lifecycle components and Methods. Currently my code looks like this.  Any advice appreciated!

```
export default class GooleMapComponent extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props)


  var version = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 22);

// this line below is necessary because often the props are not available when constructor is called
 if (this.props.mapData) {  
  markerPosition = {lat: this.props.mapParams.latitude, lng: this.props.mapParams.longitude}
  centrePosition=  {lat: this.props.mapParams.latitude, lng: this.props.mapParams.longitude}
}

else ..... // more logic to catch this case
```

Comment: If you are willing to take a shortcut and follow best practices, I would suggest you looking into [react-meteor-data](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/react-meteor-data) package